# AmChart active only 1 bullet

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm using [AmChart](https://www.amcharts.com/) and I would like to active the bullet but only if at the place of the cursor so I have :

```
 var defaultStockChartData = {
   ...
   "ChartCursor": 
    {
        "cursorColor": "#000000",
        "color": "#000000",
        "cursorAlpha": 0.5,
        "bulletSize" : 8,
        "bulletsEnabled" : true
    },
...
enter code here
```

But i get this result :

[image]

How can I do to only make appear the bullet when the cursor is on it?

Answer (score 0):

If it's can help someone I find a way to do it. You need to put the opacity of the bullet at 0 in the graph and at 1 in the chartCursorSettings:

```
 "chartCursorSettings": 
        {
            "enabled":true,
            "graphBulletAlpha":1,
            "bulletsEnabled" : true
        },
...
 "panels" : [ {

            "percentHeight" : 70,
            "showCategoryAxis" : true,

            "stockGraphs" : [ {
                "type" : "line",
                "id" : "g1",
                "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                "bulletColor": "#000000",
                "bullet": "round",
                "bulletAlpha" : 0,
                "bulletBorderAlpha" : 0,
            } ]
```